# Want to compare dates, but SQLExpression.date(java.time.LocalDate) cannot be applied

Tags: querydsl

I had earlier query like this:

```
public List<Human> findAllHumansWithPets(){

    QHuman human = QHuman.human;
    QPet pet = QPet.pet;

    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

    //Joda-Time
    LocalDate first = new LocalDate(1990, 01, 01);
    LocalDate last = new LocalDate(1990, 02, 01);

    return query.from(human)
            .innerJoin(human.pet, pet)
            .where(SQLExpressions.date(human.age).between(first.toDate(), last.toDate()))
            .list(order);
}
```

And it was working just fine. Now I updated `age` variable in my Human POJO to use java.time.LocalDate instead of org.joda.time.LocalDate. Querydsl didn't like that and is now complaining about parameter of `SQLExpression.date`.

```
    //java.time.LocalDate
    LocalDate first = LocalDate.of(1990, 01, 01);
    LocalDate last = LocalDate.of(1990, 02, 01);

    return query.from(human)
            .innerJoin(human.pet, pet)
            .where(SQLExpressions.date(human.age).between(first, last))
            .list(order);
    }
```

> DateTimeExpression<java.lang.Comparable> in SQLExpressions cannot be applied to com.mysema.query.types.path.DatePath<java.time.LocalDate>

I can't seem to find any workaround about this issue. Would be nice to prevent going back to Joda-Time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Querydsl version do you use?

Comment: 3.6.9 which is the newest I can find from mvnrepository.com

Comment: Oh, I found version 4.0.6 (they were under different groupId) and upgraded to it. It still says the same, only the path changed. `in SQLExpressions cannot be applied to com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.DatePath<java.time.LocalDate>`

Answer (score 2):

```
DateExpression.currentDate(LocalDate.class).between(..., ...)
DateExpression.currentDate(LocalDateTime.class).between(..., ...)
```